# You Don't Know JS: Up & Going - example problem

Tags: javascript, equality

In page 38 I found - arrays are by default coerced to strings by simply
joining all the values with commas (,) in between. You might think
that two arrays with the same contents would be == equal, but
they’re not:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];
var c = "1,2,3";
a == c; // true
b == c; // true
a == b; // false
```

But when I run my code like the following:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];
var c = "1,2,3";    
console.log(typeof a == c); // false
console.log(typeof b == c); // false
console.log(typeof a == b); // false
```

I got different answers! Why typeof a == c and typeof b == c is false here?

Comment: You're comparing `typeof a == c`, rather than `typeof a == typeof c`.

Answer (score 1):

its doing

```
typeof a == c

 => (typeof a) == c

 => "object" == c // which is false
```

basically `typeof` operator works before `==` sign

---

My cliche advice, always use paranthesis to make your intent clear

`typeof (a==b)` vs `(typeof a) == b`

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator returns the type of the content of a variable as a string. So if your variable `a` contains an array, `typeof a` will return the string `"object"` (as arrays are a special kind of objects).

So `typeof a == c` and `typeof b == c` compare the string `"object"` with the string `"1,2,3"`. As they are obviously not the same, this returns false.

Note that the `typeof` operator has a higher precedence than the `==` operator.